# Google sheets importxml failure - Can't find the correct path to table from the link

Tags: html, xml, xpath, google-sheets

I'm trying to retrieve a table which is updating twice per day. On other websites i was able to find the element but i saw that the way i see don't work on all websites where i tried.

In this case the issue is:
In **google sheets** using **importxml**, i can't find the correct path to table from the link or identify the element.

The website for this example is: http://lotopolonia.com/tabel/arhiva/index.php

**1.** I need to retrieve the dates and numbers.

**2.** They are updated twice per day and being updated in my sheet with adding just the last line at the top of the others. But this one after i solve the first one.

I looked at xpath tutorial from w3c and understood the syntax a bit.
The problem is how to identify correctly the elements and nodes in the inspector to retrieve the data i need.

Also, i've installed a chrome extension (XPath Helper) which shows xpath better that what i got from chrome.

**I tried the following:**

```js
=IMPORTXML("http://lotopolonia.com/tabel/arhiva/index.php","//table[@class='table_01']/tbody/tr[@class='second_row']/td[@class='colon2']")

=IMPORTXML("http://lotopolonia.com/tabel/arhiva/index.php","//table[@class='table_01']/tbody/tr[@class='second_row']/td[*]")

=IMPORTXML("http://lotopolonia.com/tabel/arhiva/index.php","//table[@class='table_01']/tbody/tr[@class='first_row'][1]/td[*]")

=IMPORTXML("http://lotopolonia.com/tabel/arhiva/index.php","//*[@class='table_01']/table/tbody/tr[@class='first_row'][1]/td[*]")

=IMPORTXML("http://lotopolonia.com/tabel/arhiva/index.php","//table[@class='table_01']/tbody/tr[3]/td[*]")

=IMPORTXML("http://lotopolonia.com/tabel/arhiva/index.php","//table[@class='table_01']/tbody/tr[*]/td[*]")

=IMPORTXML("http://lotopolonia.com/tabel/arhiva/index.php","//table[@class='table_01']/tbody/tr[@class='second_row'][1]/child::td[*]")
```

The formula looks ok, without errors, but at all above requests i get the same result: ***imported content is empty***

Unfortunately i ran out of ideas and how to interpret that elements...

Any ideea how to go on?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer? I used `//table[@class='table_01']/tr[position()>2]` as a xpath. "A1" has `http://lotopolonia.com/tabel/arhiva/index.php`.

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//table[@class='table_01']/tr[position()>2]")
```

- Using `table[@class='table_01']`, retrieve the table.
- Using `tr[position()>2]`, retrieve the dates and numbers.

#### Result :

[image]

#### Note :

- If you want to retrieve the whole table, please use `=IMPORTXML(A1,"//table[@class='table_01']/tr")`.

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hmm, NICE!. I knew that i was already going to far with variations of the formula and it is for sure a simple one.

Comment: @ilvphoto Thank you for replying. Was this xpath solved your issue?

Comment: I suppose for the next updates it will update automaticaly and it will delete the last rows from the sheet (because on their page there are a certain number of lines)?

This question brings me to the second point in the initial question regarding updating the file without erasing old data.

I wish to make some frequency calculations to see how it works and also i think i will try monthly range and they will need to stack. Maybe gather them on another sheet to keep them safe?
Thanks a lot for your response.
For now i voted you but i'm low level and they are not public votes yet ;-(

Comment: @ilvphoto I'm really sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Also can they be placed in reverse order? Last date to be first, in the same formula or i need to make it separated?

Comment: You helped... why you said that? It works perfectly.

Comment: @ilvphoto Thank you for your concern. But I'm sorry because I couldn't solve completely your issue.

Comment: I will stop answering here because i see it will clutter the answers. You answered the important one now. The table is working. And it was a simple solution. Maybe somebody else will know that. Thanks again a lot. Cheers